# How do deal with React HOC nesting

Tags: reactjs

I really appreciate HOCs in React. It is really cool stuff:

```
export default withStyles(styleSheet)(MyComponent);
```

But one day I have found out that there are couple of nested HOCs on lot of components in my project:

```
export default 
  withCheckingAccess(ACCESS)(
    withHoc1(
      withHoc2(
        withHoc3(
          connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styleSheet)(MyComponent))
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

That really looks ugly, so I'm interested what is the best practice or, maybe, a good NPM library to deal with that. For example to transform it to:

```
export default awesomeHocsDealer(
  [
    withCheckingAccess(ACCESS),
    withHoc1,
    withHoc2,
    withHoc3,
    withStyles(styleSheet)
  ],
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent),
);
```

Comment: That would be trivial to write yourself, surely? Something like `const apply = (funcs, target) => funcs.reverse().reduce((result, func) => func(result), target);`. Also `connect(...)` could just as easily be in the array with the other HOCs.

Comment: thanks, of course if nothing else, i'll do it by my self. But i came here for advice how to make it better, because i really dont think i am first who desided to deal with that

Comment: If you want to find libraries, note that this is called *function composition* and is common in functional programming. It looks like Redux provides an implementation for you, for example: https://redux.js.org/api/compose.

Comment: thanks, i'll dig around compose

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that is it. redux compose that is the function i asked about. So now i can do `export default compose(withHoc1,  withHoc2, connect)(MyComponent)`. Thanks! Could you please write it as an anwser... ? I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Note that the new proposal of react Hooks address this exact problem! But it's only an experimental proposal. I also heard about ReactDevTools plugins cleaning HOC's in the chrome devTools.